# Dynamic-Data-Display WPF Changing the ChartPlotter's default behaviour to moving instead of scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, dynamic-data-display

I have some data that comes via messages to my chart. It's a electric current over time (seconds) chart. How can I change the behaviour of the FitToView mode (or write a different one) so that the plotter doesn't zoom out and scale to fit the whole line graph, but move left instead, showing for example only the 100 last seconds?

I thought of calculating minimums and maximums every message and changing the plotters restraints explicitly but it doesn't seem very optimal. Also due to the fact that I would have to set the restraints in code-behind but all the data is in the ViewModel (using MVVM with caliburn).

Edit: I've found the functionality for this (adding WidthFollowConstraint to the FitToView constraints) but the linegraph gets moved more than the axis and after that it compensates back to where it should be, making the whole graph glitch out on every iteration. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently I forgot to answer this.

I made the graph move instead of scale by adding a MinimalSizeConstraint and a FollowWidthConstraint to the ConstraintCollection in the constructor of the D3 Viewport2D class. The names are pretty selfexplanitory. Basically this changes the FitToView funtion of the graph to the desired behaviour